# Python AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'itertuples'

Tags: python, loops, polygon, geopandas

I am trying to get graphs from polygons from a shp-file. An error occurs that the object has no attribute 'itertuples'. Does anyone know how to solve the problem?

```
import geopandas as gpd
import osmnx as ox
path_to_folder = r'/Users/xxx/Desktop/Example/cities.shp'
cities = gpd.read_file =('/Users/xxx/Desktop/Example/cities.shp')

for item in cities.itertuples():
    print(item.gen)
    graph = ox.graph_from_polygon(item.geometry)
    ox.save_graphml(graph, filepath = '/Users/xxx/Desktop/' + item.gen + '.graphml')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [35], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 for item in cities.itertuples():
      2     print(item.gen)
      3     graph = ox.graph_from_polygon(item.geometry)

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'itertuples'
```

I tried to solve this problem with "replace" or "join", but I actually do not know how to incorporate it into the code.

Comment: You probably want `cities = gpd.read_file('...')`…?

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your code:

```
cities = gpd.read_file ='/Users/xxx/Desktop/Example/cities.shp'
```

should be

```
cities = gpd.read_file('/Users/xxx/Desktop/Example/cities.shp')
```

Otherwise `cities` is just given the value `'/Users/xxx/Desktop/Example/cities.shp'` which is... a `str` so you can't `itertuples()` on it! That's why copy pastes are risky!

Comment: I think its not the problem, it has also worked with other examples. I tried, what you said, but the error still occurs.